# Create phonegap app with framework7 latest version

Tags: phonegap, html-framework-7

I created a phonegap app with framework7 but the default version is 1.4 where framework7 is now at 3.3

is there a way to start the phonegap app with latest framework7 versions?  a lot of the functions do not work with the default 1.4 in phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the last version of Framework7 working in your app you need to migrate from v1 to v3.

The change is not simply matter of updating files. You can find some more detailed instructions in the [migration guide](https://blog.framework7.io/migration-to-framework7-v3-928a21a1eac9) from the Framework7 author himself.